# Change log time format of OpenSSH

Tags: openssh

OpenSSH log in my system are spitting log in following format.

```
Aug 21 14:34:44 systemHostName sshd[1952]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
```

I need to get the year also, in the log time. something like following

```
2012 Aug 21 14:34:44 systemHostName sshd[1952]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
```

I tried to look into `sshd_config` and other web resources but could not find anything useful.

Anybody know, how to change openSSH log time format?

Answer (score 0):

It is `syslog`, not `sshd` time format, depends on your syslog implementation, though I haven't seen anyone using the year there.